# Simultaneous aggregate count and full count

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, count

I have a table `events` like this:

```
create table events
(
    correlation_id char(26) not null,
    user_id        bigint,
    task_id        bigint not null,
    location_id    bigint,
    type           bigint not null,
    created_at     timestamp(6) with time zone not null,
    constraint events_correlation_id_created_at_user_id_unique
        unique (correlation_id, created_at, user_id)
);
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

The table holds records of tasks being performed, that look like this:

```
insert into events (correlation_id, user_id, task_id, location_id, type, created_at)
values  ('01CN4HP4AN0000000000000001', 4, 58, 30, 0, '2018-08-17 18:17:15.348629+00'),
        ('01CN4HP4AN0000000000000001', 4, 58, 30, 1, '2018-08-17 18:17:22.852299+00'),
        ('01CN4HP4AN0000000000000001', 4, 58, 30, 99, '2018-08-17 18:17:25.535593+00'),
        ('01CN4J9SZ80000000000000003', 4, 97, 30, 0, '2018-08-17 18:28:00.104093+00'),
        ('01CN4J9SZ80000000000000003', 4, 97, 30, 98, '2018-08-17 18:28:49.04584+00'),
        ('01CN4J9SZ80000000000000003', 4, 97, 30, 99, '2018-08-17 18:29:09.01684+00'),
        ('01CN4JC1430000000000000004', 4, 99, 30, 0, '2018-08-17 18:29:12.963264+00'),
        ('01CN4JC1430000000000000004', 4, 99, 30, 3, '2018-08-17 18:29:47.83452+00'),
        ('01CN4JC1430000000000000004', 4, 99, 30, 98, '2018-08-17 18:31:01.86342+00'),
        ('01CN4JC1430000000000000004', 4, 99, 30, 99, '2018-08-17 18:32:09.272632+00'),
        ('01CN4KJCDY0000000000000005', 139, 97, 30, 0, '2018-08-17 18:50:09.725668+00'),
        ('01CN4KJCDY0000000000000005', 139, 97, 30, 3, '2018-08-17 18:50:11.842+00'),
        ('01CN4KJCDY0000000000000005', 139, 97, 30, 99, '2018-08-17 18:51:42.240895+00'),
        ('01CNC4G1Y40000000000000008', 139, 99, 30, 0, '2018-08-20 17:00:40.26043+00'),
        ('01CNC4G1Y40000000000000008', 139, 99, 30, 99, '2018-08-20 17:00:47.583501+00');
```

> ```
> INSERT 0 15
> ```

Certain values of the `type` column indicate emergencies. I can use this simple query to get a count of how many tasks had each type of emergency occur during their performance:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT correlation_id), type
FROM events
WHERE type IN (3, 5, 97, 98)
GROUP BY type;
```

| count | type |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 98 |

> ```
> SELECT 2
> ```

I can also use this simple query to get a count of how many tasks had ***any*** type of emergency occur during their performance:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT correlation_id)
FROM events
WHERE type IN (3, 5, 97, 98);
```

| count |
| --- |
| 3 |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

The question is this: is there a way to combine these two queries so that I can get the total and also the breakdown by type in a single query?

I cannot just add up the `count` column, because a `correlation_id` value can have more than one emergency type associated with it. In the example above, there are three total `correlation_id` values with emergencies, but adding the `count` column would come up to four.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zO9Y8gQ4)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want is `ROLLUP`:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT correlation_id), type
FROM events
WHERE type IN (3, 5, 97, 98)
GROUP BY ROLLUP (type);
```

Comment: For the OP, have a look at `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS` and `GROUP BY CUBE` as well. They are variations of `GROUP BY ROLLUP` and may come in handy in other situations.

Comment: I suggest you to read [GROUPING SETS, CUBE, and ROLLUP](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS) section of the documentation which has simple examples and is easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

I would make simple union with some fixed value for all types

```
SELECT type, COUNT(DISTINCT correlation_id)
FROM events
WHERE type IN (3, 5, 97, 98)
GROUP BY type
UNION
SELECT 0, COUNT(DISTINCT correlation_id)
FROM events
WHERE type IN (3, 5, 97, 98)
order by 1
```